# How do you delete a set string from a word (sWord) in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I need help deleting "fe" from sWord in the System.out part of the code. Just need a quick answer on how to do this, its clear that you cant simply subtract it but I don't know how else to do it, thanks for the help.  BTW this is not the full code, simply an excerpt.

```
else if (sWord.substring(sWord.length()-2,sWord.length()).equalsIgnoreCase("fe"))
        {
        System.out.println("The Plural of" + sWord + "is" + **(sWord-("fe"))** + "ves");
        }
```

Comment: Are you always going to have a fixed sentence? Then use replace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only at the end of the string (as in your example), you could do

```
sWord = sWord.substring(0, sWord.length()-2);
```

If you want to remove "fe" from anywhere in the `sWord` you could use,

```
sWord = sWord.replace("fe", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
sWord.replace("fe", "");
```

For more information about replace you can take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) method:

```
String newSWord = sWord.replace("fe", "");
```

If you need some advanced String modification, you can have a look at [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library - [StringUtils replace() method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).